Differences between STFT and DGT
What’s the main difference between short-time Fourier transform (STFT) and discrete Gabor transform (DGT)? Based on the definitions in the Wikipedia page (and other textbooks), it seems that they are both the same.
MATLAB has a routine stft to compute STFT. There is also a package called LTFAT which has a routine named dgt. What’s the difference between these two routines?


Based on the definitions in the Wikipedia page (and other textbooks), it seems that they are both the same.

The Wikipedia page says states:

The Gabor transform, ... is a special case of the  short-time Fourier transform.

If you perform a continuous short time Fourier Transform with a Gaussian window of a specific variance you have done a Gabor Transform. If you perform and STFT with different window you have done a different transform. In other words: the STFT comes in a lot of flavors and one of them is the Gabor Transform.

MATLAB has a routine stft to compute STFT

Careful here. The Matlab function implements the discrete STFT not the continuous STFT. There are significant differences between the two. The same probably holds for the discrete Gabor Transform .

One thing with the inverse Discrete Gabor Transform is that the Gaussian window (which is the window used in the Gabor Transform) is not complementary.  It is not true that: $$ \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} w[n-mH] = 1  \qquad \forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z} $$ when $$w[n] = A e^{-\pi \alpha n^2} \qquad \alpha>0$$ unless the hop $H=1$. If the window function is not complementary, then how do we guarantee that the inverse STFT adds up to the original signal going into the STFT?

BTW, I used the Gabor Transform (without knowing its name) in time scaling algorithm described this old paper.  Using the Gaussian window is mathematically quite convenient when the signal being analyzed is a sinusoid with changing frequency and changing amplitude.  But in reconstruction, I multiplied by a window correction function to turn the Gaussian window into a complementary window like the Hann window.

@Hilmar, thanks for the answer. My question is actually about the difference between discrete time STFT and discrete Gabor transform. Is it possible to reise Matlab stft function to compute a discrete Gabor transform?

@RBJ, for perfect reconstruction the synthesis window should be the canonical dual & tight window of the analysis window. Btw, thanks for sharing the paper.

@AHT , you might read this other answer.  For the STFT to perfectly reconstruct, you need this property of complementarity.
